# Overriding object's toString makes ListView row not clickable?

Tags: java, android

I'm having a weird problem. I have a simple ListView with an onItemClickListener. When I override the list object's toString it displays correctly, but clicks stop working. When I just call super in the toString the clicks work fine.

from onCreate:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(this, 0, 0, CalendarActivity.satellites);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Satellite>(this, R.layout.search_cell, R.id.name, CalendarActivity.satellites));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SearchActivity.this, DayActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

Satellite:

```
public class Satellite {

public String url;
public boolean active;
public String name;
public int id;

public ArrayList<Date> dates;

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (!name.isEmpty()) { //note that this still fails the onClick
        return name;
    } else {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

Whats going on?

Comment: Maybe `name` has `null` value when being used in the `toString` method. Isn't a catlog file where you can check the errors thrown by the Android emulator? If yes, please copy/pate the error message that is placed there when you select an element in your ListView.

Comment: There are no errors thrown and none of the names are null.

Comment: Update: putting `return name + super.toString()` also works, but `return name + " "` does not.

Comment: Very odd indeed. By the way, you use the ` symbol to encapsulate code in comments :) ( ` )`like this`( ` )